# Real alternative to outerglowbitmapeffect

Tags: .net, wpf

I read about the alternative DropShadowEffect, but in my case I cannot use it.

My window has an own styling and is transparent. I want to add an outer glow to it, which is now deprecated (outerGlowBitmapEffect).

The DropShadowEffect will add a constant color behind my window which becomes visible due to the transparent window. Therefore it is no real alternative to an outer glow.

What else can I do to get an outer glow realized?

EDIT:

```
<Window x:Class="DVR.Gui.GuiTemplates.Dialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Dialog" Width="400"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" ResizeMode="NoResize" 
        ShowInTaskbar="False" WindowStyle="None"
        UseLayoutRounding="True"
        AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" SizeToContent="Height">
    <Border Margin="10">


        <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCFFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10,10,10,10" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrush}" />
        </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            OTHER CONTENT
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Comment: But then how do want the outer glow to your transparent window? Around the rectangular border of the window only?

Comment: Yes. The window has a 1px border. Only outside the border I want to have a shadow / glow. The window background is not transparent at all. It has an opacity.

Comment: Can you paste the XAML of what you are trying with your window?

Comment: I added a code sample to my question. Missing the part how to add a glow.